# Python dataframe conditional column population

Tags: python, string, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

I need to populate values in a column based on whether or not values in a different column contain certain alphabets, and some rules.

For example:

Here's my starting dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
testdata1 = [('A', ['3c', '20b', '9']),
     ('B', ['Prod1', 'Prod2', 'Prod3']),
     ('C', ['', '', '']),
     ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(testdata1)
df
```

Here's my target dataframe:

```
targetdf = [('A', ['3c', '20b', '9']),
     ('B', ['Prod1', 'Prod2', 'Prod3']),
     ('C', ['15.00', '40.00', '9']),
     ]
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(targetdf)
df2
```

In my example above, if the cell in Column A contains 'c', the corresponding cell in Column C should contain the result of the multiplication of the number part of the cell in Column A with 5. If the cell in Column A contains 'b', the corresponding cell in Column C should contain the result of the multiplication of the number part of the cell in Column A with 2. If the cell in Column A contains no alphabets (i.e. it is a number), copy the number to the corresponding cell in Column C.

I think the solution will involve the use of "contains" to search for 'c' or 'b'. Perhaps an If Statement? I am not sure. I certainly need help extracting the number part of the cell in Column A and populating the correct value in Column C. I am fairly new to Python.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
def parse_data(x):
    if 'c' in x:
        num = int(x.split('c')[0])
        return num * 5
    elif 'b' in x:
        num = int(x.split('b')[0])
        return num * 2
    else:
        return x

df['C'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: parse_data(x))

     A      B   C
0   3c  Prod1  15
1  20b  Prod2  40
2    9  Prod3   9
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way:

```
In [17]: mapping={'c':' * 5', 'b':' * 2'}

In [18]: df['C'] = pd.eval(df.A.replace(mapping, regex=True))

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
     A      B   C
0   3c  Prod1  15
1  20b  Prod2  40
2    9  Prod3   9
```

Explanation:

```
In [20]: df.A.replace(mapping, regex=True)
Out[20]:
0     3 * 5
1    20 * 2
2         9
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: I like this solution too, nice concise and effective, +1

Answer (score 0):

I'd use regex and lookups like

```
In [538]: (df.A.str.extract('(\d+)(\w+)?', expand=True)
             .replace({1: {'c':5,'b':2,np.nan:1}}).astype(int)
             .prod(1))
Out[538]:
0    15
1    40
2     9
dtype: int32

In [539]: df['C'] = (df.A.str.extract('(\d+)(\w+)?', expand=True)
                       .replace({1: {'c':5,'b':2,np.nan:1}}).astype(int)
                       .prod(1))
In [540]: df
Out[540]:
     A      B   C
0   3c  Prod1  15
1  20b  Prod2  40
2    9  Prod3   9
```

Details

```
In [542]: df.A.str.extract('(\d+)(\w+)?', expand=True)
Out[542]:
    0    1
0   3    c
1  20    b
2   9  NaN

In [543]: df.A.str.extract('(\d+)(\w+)?', expand=True).replace({1: {'c':5,'b':2,np.nan:1}})
Out[543]:
    0  1
0   3  5
1  20  2
2   9  1
```

Comment: This works too. Thanks for helping. Your code is very advanced to me. Could you explain any advantages of this particular approach?